# Should I avoid using database views in Laravel projects?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, view

Maintaining database views in mysql is sometimes cumbersome. When you change a referred table you have to alter the table and there is no clean way to do that in migrations (`DB::unprepared()`). I guess using [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) in models is more maintainable. Isn't it?  Does it has negative effect on the performance.

Comment: There are a lot of things to factor in here, so I don't think there's any real advice that can encompass any future project you might work on. Query scopes might be more maintainable in the context of a Laravel application, but they're not exactly equivalent to views, which makes this kind of a weird comparison. Views can have better performance in some cases, but that is subject to the database system you're using. So the bottom line is that you should be using whatever works best for that particular project. Perfect maintainability can take some hits in cases where performance is paramount.

Comment: I agree with Bogdan about query scopes. They are totally different things...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big your project is and I don't have many elements to judge this situation perfectly.

However, working with views means depending on the underlying database system. Obviously it has its pros and cons, but I would prefer to decouple my software components.

What if you change, in the future, switching from *MySQL* to *MongoDB*?

Maybe, you could use a cache system, like Redis or Memcached (and Laravel **already has a ready-to-use service** for it).

As I told you before, I am making this suggestion basically because I think about the software scalability and components decoupling.

Here you can learn about the basic use of the Cache Service: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache

Also, if you have some confidence with design patterns, you can implement a really elegant solution using some stacked repositories alongside the decorator pattern.

You can find some interesting articles about the topic here:

- http://culttt.com/2014/02/03/laravel-4-cache-service/
- http://culttt.com/2014/04/23/decorator-pattern/

Yes, they're about Laravel 4 but the concept can be easily adopted in a Laravel 5.* project.

Hope it was useful!

EDIT: as I told in the following comments, if you don't want to start with something like Redis or Memcached, you can always use the *filesystem-based* Cache.

Comment: I agreed. However, to play devil's advocate - how often does one change their database system? Sometimes it's better to use the tools available in the way that allows you to write the apis you need today, instead of thinking about the changes that may never happen in the future.

Comment: I partly agree with you. What you say is right, but in my life I've seen many cases where spending a couple more hours could  dramatically change everything. Also, if you like the idea of a Cache service you can always use the **filesystem based one**. It can be a great starter and it requires nothing to configure! :)